# Функция запускается сама по себе. PHP

Tags: php, html

Почему функция вызывается сразу при обновлении страницы сама по себе? И почему она потом не вызывается по клику?

```
<?php
function heloys () {
$filename = 'reyt.txt';
$texts = 'some text';
file_put_contents($filename, $texts, FILE_APPEND); } 
?> 
<input type="button"  value="knopka" onclick="<?php heloys()?>" >
```

Comment: ого треш ) а чег овы добиваетесь ?))) что у вас лежит в `reyt.txt`?

Comment: Вы, видимо, вообще не понимаете базовую архитектуру веба и принципы его работы

Comment: выполняется потому что onclick - это событие в js. Когда js подписывается на событие, то в нем уже выполнился `php`, т к `php` выполняется на сервере.

Comment: если вы хотите чтобы функция выполнялась по клику кнопки, то сделайте запрос на сервер и обработайте там его.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали выше в комментариях - аякс запрос. Конструкции разные бывают, например такая:

```
<button class="call">Нажми меня</button>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$('.call').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "click.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: 0,
        data: {
            "z": 'z',

        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {}
    })



});
</script>
```

PHP click.php

```
if (isset($_POST['z']))
{
    helloys();
}
function helloys()
{
    file_put_contents('1.txt', 'привет пользователь ', FILE_APPEND); 
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>'true'));
    return;
}
```

Готово о.о